# typeof(T).GetFields() returning zero length array

Tags: c#, .net, object

I am trying to get a list of fields from an object.  I have confirmed that the object is being passed in with this call:

```
var account = SymitarInquiryDeserializer.Deserialize<SymitarAccount>(jString);
```

When I try to get the fields it returns a zero length array and I can't see what I am doing wrong here.

My object definition:

```
public class SymitarAccount
{
    public int PositionalIndex { get; set; }
    /// <summary>IQ: ~JID: Account/Share Id (format: 0000)</summary>
    [SymitarInquiryDataFormat("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    /// <summary>IQ: ~JCLOSEDATE: Account/Share Closed Date where 00000000 is still open (format: YYYYMMDD)</summary>
    [SymitarInquiryDataFormat("CLOSEDATE")]
    public DateTime? CloseDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsClosed { get; set; }
    /// <summary>IQ: ~JDIVTYPE: Account/Share Div Type (format: 0)</summary>
    [SymitarInquiryDataFormat("DIVTYPE")]
    public int DivType { get; set; }
    /// <summary>IQ: ~JBALANCE: Account/Share Balance (format: 0.00)</summary>
    [SymitarInquiryDataFormat("BALANCE")]
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    /// <summary>IQ: ~JAVAILABLEBALANCE: Account/Share Avaialable Balance (format: 0.00)</summary>
    [SymitarInquiryDataFormat("AVAILABLEBALANCE")]
    public decimal AvailableBalance { get; set; }
}
```

My method to get fields:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string str) where T : new()
{
    var result = new T();
    ....
    // Get fields of type T
    var fields = typeof(T).GetFields();    //BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are not fields but properties. Use `GetProperties` instead:

```
var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
```

Answer (score 2):

`GetFields` returns public variables. What you're after is the property names which you can get by calling [GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void FindFieldNames<T>(List<T> data)
{
      foreach (var prop in data.GetType().GetProperties())
      {           
           Console.WriteLine($@"{prop.Name}");                
      }    
}
```